# In c# windows desktop when I build project using command Line 'dotnet build' command than getting error

Tags: c#, windows, desktop

In c# windows desktop when I build project using command Line dotnet build command than getting error
because client having not visual studio on machine so I am trying to change one file and after change build the project because i am  running exe

Not allow to change project version.

below error which i am facing
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/grhJg.png)

Comment: Did you visit the link that it gave you in the message? it *literally tells you what to do* - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/msbuild/resolvecomreference-task?view=vs-2022#msb4803-error

Comment: What the error tries to tell you is, that the project targets the .Net-Framework while you only have .Net Core installed

Answer (score 1):

The command-line gave you a link; if we visit that, we end up [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/msbuild/resolvecomreference-task?view=vs-2022#msb4803-error) which says (among other things):

> This task is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild, which is what's used when you run the `dotnet build` command from the command line. Try building the project by invoking MSBuild.exe from the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt, since this uses the .NET Framework version of MSBuild.

So... do that.